# unattended-upgrades stuck at linux-image postinst configure

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

One of my Ubuntu boxes is has unattended-upgrades stuck, and is locking apt so I can't do any further upgrades :

```
20027 ?        S     25:23 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
20474 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 10 --configure linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic:amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic:am
20475 pts/0    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/perl /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic.postinst configure
20484 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/4:1H]
20518 pts/0    S+     0:00 run-parts --verbose --exit-on-error --arg=4.4.0-72-generic --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic /etc/kernel/posti
20569 pts/0    S+     0:00 /bin/sh -e /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
20571 pts/0    S+     0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -c -t -k 4.4.0-72-generic -b /boot
```

Could someone give me some pointers on how to fix this? Thanks.